# View full width that does not resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, width

Hello I would like to create an effect like the one on the home page of bootstrap 2.3.2 - http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/

The effect is that of 'view full width, which cuts in automatically

I managed to get a full picture width

```
.cut {
     max-width: 450px;
     overflow: hidden;
}

.cut img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Unfortunately, the 'image is resized in the mobile, while I would prefer that you cut

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, which effect are you referring to?

Comment: What image are you referring to on the bootstrap website?

Comment: didnt get your question..Are you looking to make responsive

Answer (score 0):

You want this little responsive thing? (*try resizing the window*)

http://jsfiddle.net/q78DA/1/

**CSS**:

```
.cut img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="cut">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/600/400">
</div>
```

This is called having **responsive design**.

[Would you like to know more? http://www.geekation.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Geekation_WouldYouLikeToKnowMore.jpg](http://www.geekation.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/Geekation_WouldYouLikeToKnowMore.jpg)

Try to dig in here: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/08/choosing-a-responsive-image-solution/